# Too many pixels even using the ee.Reducer.mean

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to create a NDVI-time series chart, but it the result said there are too many pixels, so I tried to use the  `ee.Reducer.mean` function but it still showed the same error. Does it mean the reduced function is not working?

```
// Define a region of pixels to reduce and chart a time series for.
var region = ROI;

// Define an image collection time series to chart, MODIS vegetation indices
// in this case.
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2015-01-01', '2020-01-01'))
  .select(['NDVI']);
  

// Function to reduce each image in the Image Collection to the mean value
var reduceToMean = function(image) {
  var mean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: ROI,
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
  }).get('NDVI');
  
  return image.set('mean_NDVI', mean);
};

// Map the reduceToMean function over the Image Collection
var imgColReduced = imgCol.map(reduceToMean);

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: imgColReduced,
  region: ROI,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'
})
.setSeriesNames(['NDVI'])
.setOptions({
  title: 'Average Vegetation Index Value by Date',
  hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Vegetation index (x1e4)',
    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
  },
  lineWidth: 5,
  colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
  curveType: 'function'
});
print(chart);
```

Here is the error message:
Collection.first: Error in map(ID=2015_01_01):
Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 12258620, but maxPixels allows only 10000000.
Ensure that you are not aggregating at a higher resolution than you intended; that is a frequent cause of this error. If not, then you may set the 'maxPixels' argument to a limit suitable for your computation; set 'bestEffort' to true to aggregate at whatever scale results in 'maxPixels' total pixels; or both.

Comment: The pixel limit applies regardless of what reducer you use. The error message explains how to fix it.

Comment: @Aaron Zuspan
, I have tried the solution: 
1. Set the maxPixels to 1e9/1e10
2. Added 'bestEffort' to true
3. Both above
but it still didn't work. Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Ah, it looks like there's a maximum pixel limit for both `reduceRegions` and `ui.Chart.image.series`, but it's only adjustable for `reduceRegions` (increasing `maxPixels` lets you add `imgColReduced` to the map, but doesn't let you add the chart because it has its own limit). I think your choice to export the data and graph separately is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the solutions, which are:

1. Set the maxPixels to 1e9/1e10
2. Added 'bestEffort' to true
3. Added 'tileScale' to 16
4. Both above

But they didn't work at all. Therefore, instead of making chart on the GEE, I decided to export the csv. to drive and make the graph at other places.